# Google map | jQuery | Zoom level produces error

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have created a Google Map Object in my page and I want to change the Google map zoom level by entering the zoom level in a text box.

The code I use is the following:

```
var zoom = parseInt($('#gm_zoom').val(), 10);
map.setZoom(zoom);
```

Where `#gm_zoom` is the text input where I enter the zoom level and `map` is my Google Map Object.

Do you see anything wrong in this code? When I de-comment this portion of code I get the following in my Chrome console:

```
<error>
    Vd
    Q.trigger
    Af
    H.set
    (anonymous function)
    Af
    (anonymous function)
    Q.trigger
    Af
    (anonymous function)
    Q.trigger
    Af
    H.set
    ...
    (repeated many times)
    ...
    (anonymous function)
    gmap_build_sc
    manage_events
    Q.trigger
    Af
    H.set
    (anonymous function)
```

Any idea on how to solve that issue ?

**Note** : In the same function I try to update the zoom level I also change the map type, latitude, and longitude with no error. Only the above code produces the problem!

Comment: place an `alert(zoom);` in between the two lines of code. My money's on the value being off.

Comment: I have use console.log and I get the correct integer value

Comment: A link to a map that exhibits the problem or a jsfiddle might let us help.

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot place my code in jsfiddle, because this is a WordPress Shortcode builder that has mixed JavaScript with PHP. :(